# CreateProcessAsUser: how to open file with default application?

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

I am using CreateProcessAsUser in C++ code to open an application impersonating a user. This works well, if an executable is given but fails with a non-executable file.

What is the simplest way to open non-executable files with their default application with CreateProcessAsUser.

I need a solution **other** than via:

```
cmd.exe /S /C ""path_to_my_file""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is as follows:

1. From the original process, process A say, use `CreateProcessAsUser` to create a new process, process B, say. Process B runs as a different user.
2. Pass to process B command line arguments that specify the file that you want to open.
3. From process B call `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx` to open the other file.

Comment: To expand on this, process B could be `cmd.exe` (if the OP hadn't already ruled that solution out) or a dedicated separate executable, or it could be the same executable as the parent process but with a command-line switch that tells it what to do.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks David and Harry for this solution and the elaboration. I like the idea of self-invokation with command line switch. (@Harry: With cmd.exe no process B is necessary. It can be called directly by CreateProcessAsUser.)

Comment: If you want to get the shell to work out how to open a specific file, then, to the best of my knowledge, this approach is the only solution.

Comment: @ArikRaffaelFunke: if you're running `cmd.exe` in order to launch your document you don't need a third process (a "process C") if that's what you mean.  In this scenario the `cmd.exe` process is process B.  Presumably the reason you don't want to do that is that it opens a console window?